# How do I pass integer items of a list to a function as string arguments in Python?

Tags: python, string, list, arguments

I have a Python list consisting of integers:

```
a = [1, 2, 3]
```

I want to pass the items of this list as arguments to a function, and they must be strings:

```
myfunc("1", "2", "3")
```

How can I do it?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

So... we use the `*` operator to use a sequence as multiple arguments for a function call; and we want to convert each argument to a string. The conversion is most obviously and simply done by just passing the value to the builtin `str`; we can then just `map` that conversion function onto the list. These are all elementary techniques and all we have to do is put them together:

```
myfunc(*map(str, a))
```

Comment: The edit is too small for me to make but the parentheses around `map()` are extraneous.

Comment: Why  use an extra pair of brackets?

Comment: Just force of habit, since in the code I've written lately, the `*` is typically applied to a generator expression. I removed the extra parens and added some explanation.

Answer (score 3):

[* keyword](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/controlflow.html#unpacking-argument-lists)  can unpacking the argument list.

```
a = [1, 2, 3]
myfunc(*(str(l) for l in a))
```